# Protect sub-directory Wordpress with htpassword return page not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I followed this instruction to protect subdirectory.
https://support.hostgator.com/articles/wordpress-preventing-you-from-password-protecting-a-directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Changed to

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It can protect sub-directory in Wordpress without returning to 404 page but It seems that the website link is not valid.

Example. Website returns error page is it does not have slash at the end of domain.

Working domain: http://demodomain.com/something/

Not working domain: http://demodomain.com/something

Answer (score 1):

try the following optionsrule just below RewriteEngine On:

```
1) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]

2) #Removing trailing slash
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Add slash at the end of URL

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Or Do Following

```
# Ensure all URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What I need is to add slash at the end, not removing.

Comment: @MinhAnh I have updated my answer. please review it.